# RavenDB: Sync documents in database with data from external source

Tags: c#, synchronization, ravendb, data-synchronization

What is the **most efficient** way to sync documents in a RavenDB?

From an external source I get an `IEnumerable` of BlogPosts that I want to do the following with:

- Add new objects that are new to RavenDB
- Update existing objects
- Remove objects that were removed in the external source

The code that needs implementation:

```
public void SyncIntoRaven(IEnumerable<BlogPost> postsToSync, IDocumentStore store) {
    // TODO: Implement
    // AddNewItems(postsToSync);

    // TODO: Implement
    // RemoveDeletedItems(postsToSync);

    // TODO: Implement
    // UpdateExistingItems(postsToSync);
}
```

One could just pull out all BlogPosts from RavenDB and **sync locally** to then push all the changes back, but I want to **minimize traffic to RavenDB**. But maybe that's not the right approach either?

Comment: Sync between Raven and what? How do you track blog posts between stores - do they have the same Id for them in both stores?

Comment: @synhershko Same ID. Between RavenDB and an external source, like a generated XML-file or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sharing the same ID between your external source and RavenDB, you can do this quite easily, in an ACID fashion, and within one transaction.

Keep track of IDs that changed between sync operations, and once you have that list of ID's you can easily do this:

Open a session, add the new documents using session.Store(), load all the documents need updating or deleting using session.Load(string[]) session.Load().Lazily, make the updates (and deletions using the Deferred option), and once you are done call session.SaveChanges().

That should get you covered, and happen in only one roundtrip to the server.

Either way, you never want to do complete sync every time. You always want to use deltas.

Comment: Will this work with like >3500 IDs passed into `session.Load(string[])`?

Comment: And I can't know which documents are new without getting all the IDs from the store, right?

Comment: This should work for that amount of IDs, yes, but you may want to do this in smaller batches. You will get nulls for non-existent IDs, this is how you'd know they do not exist yet. Or via your tracking mechanism.

Comment: I'm still getting one request too much, from having to figure out which documents are in Raven, but not in the external documents, and needs to be removed. Any tips on how to work around this?

Comment: See in my comment to your Answer

Answer (score 1):

With the help in description-form from [synhershko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11021144/2429) I figured it out and wanted to share the code, simplified to show the concepts.

```
private void RefreshBlogPosts(IDocumentSession session, IList<BlogPost> parsedPosts) {
    var parsedPostsIds = parsedPosts.Select(x => x.Id);
    var storePosts = session.Load<BlogPost>(parsedPostsIds);

    // Update existing or create new posts
    for(int i = 0; i < storePosts.Count(); i++) {
        var parsedPost = parsedPosts[i];

        var storePost = storePosts[i];
        if(storePost == null) {
            storePost = parsedPost;

            session.Store(storePost);
        } else {
            // Update post's properties
        }
    }

    // Find posts IDs no longer in database
    var removedPostIds = session.Query<BlogPost>().Select(x => x.Id)
        .Where(postId => !parsedPostsIds.Contains(postId));

    foreach(var removedPostId in removedPostIds) {
        session.Advanced.Defer(new DeleteCommandData() { Key = removedPostId });
    }

    session.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: No need for session.Store if you only updated an existing object you got using Load<>(). Just update the object and SaveChanges() will take care of the rest. UoW magic.

Comment: Also, the second query will not work, .Contains() will throw NotImplementedException. The In operator is what you will usually use, but in this case it is going to be easier to just track deletions in your system and send those IDs as a separate list.

Comment: There is no `Contains` in there. I changed it, it used to be over a local collection though.

Comment: I can't track deletions in the system, RavenDB is the place of tracking and it requires above sync. Do I have to still use `session.Store` for the null-objects?

Comment: session.Store has no meaning on nulls, it will throw

Comment: `Load<>()` will return nulls for items that are not in RavenDB, when I do assign these nulls, do I have to store the nulls?

Comment: Not following. If you see a null in the BlogPost array that you got, then you know you are missing and entry and so are adding a new document under that ID.

Comment: Yes, but THEN, do I need to `session.Store` the new document? Or is your advice above about only using `SaveChanges()` enough?

Comment: It is enough to call SaveChanges() if you change an object that was loaded from Raven using Load or Query. They are tracked for changes internally. To add a new object you have to use Store.

Comment: Even for a null object returned by those methods?

Comment: A null isn't tracked, a null is nothing, it means the ID was not found on the server, hence there's nothing to track.

Comment: Thanks, that cleared that out. What about identifying the removed posts more effectively? Is it possible, or is this as good as it gets?

Comment: Not really, best way is to track deletions separately, or do soft-deletes on the original system and use the tombstone to signal the Raven copy to delete the document

Comment: Eh... could you maybe link to an article that describes above, because I've never heard of it.

Comment: Don't really know one. Ping us on the mailing list and I'll describe it there.

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting "URL too long" when I pass in around 500 IDs to find deleted posts `session.Query<BlogPost>().Where(x => !x.ID.In(externalIds))`. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Can't really find anything after Googling around a lot. It just gives a `Lazy<T>`, which I can't see how I would use without triggering the actually query to get the content of the Lazy.

Comment: You just add .Lazily to the end of your query, and after you are done you call session.Advanced.EagerlyExecute. See http://ayende.com/blog/63491/ravendb-lazy-requests

Comment: My need to see which IDs are not in RavenDB will execute the Lazy immediately, from what is described in Ayende's post. So I guess I'm stuck at this point.

Comment: Not sure what is your current approach. As I said, I would use tombstones to solve this. If this is not a good solution for you, can we take this to the mailing list please?

Comment: Also, Lazy queries in the scenario is just to force the query to be performed as POST and not GET, to bypass the "Uri too long" exception you got